# Consolidated Linq

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a collection which is being passed from method to method and various Linq operations being done on it.
When this collection finally comes to me I also do a little linq operation on it.

Now here's the question - 
Is there a way I can have a look at the consolidated Linq operations that were done to the collection before it came to me? Is there any tool\nuget package available for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here it is an important difference whether you receive an `IQueryable` (with an Expression) or an `IEnumerable`. This is almost equivalent to the question whether your collection comes from linq to sql/entites or linq to objects.

Answer (score 0):

Since LINQ tends to be lazy-evaluated, you can probably single-step through an iteration, to see what `MoveNext()` calls are made, and what LINQ functions they are exposed by.